# Documentsフォルダにある動画ファイルが再生出来ない

Tags: ios, swift5

Documentsフォルダにダウンロードした動画ファイル (*.mov, *.mp4) を再生したいと思い、
以下のコードを書きました。

しかし、同じ動画ファイルでも、①の方法では再生され、②の方法では再生されません。
moviePathの値を確認したのですが、特に問題なく、Documentsフォルダに該当の動画ファイルがありました。

1. `Bundle.main.path` で指定した場合:
   動画は再生される
2. `moviePath = localMovieFilePath! + localMovieFileName!` で指定した場合:
   動画が再生されない

info.plist の App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads は YES にしております。

どなたかわかる方、ご教授願えませんでしたでしょうか。

---

```
/// 動画を再生する
func playAnimetion() {

    let localMovieFilePath: String? = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.localMovieFilePath)
    let localMovieFileName: String? = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.localMovieFileName)
    let moviePath: String
    if (localMovieFilePath == nil || localMovieFileName == nil) {
        moviePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AdobeStock_218702675", ofType: "mov")!
    } else {
        moviePath = localMovieFilePath! + localMovieFileName!
    }
    print("moviePath = " + moviePath)
    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath))
    player.play()
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    videoView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: 質問の投稿時、タグは個別の機能として提供されていますので、タイトルに【】の形式で無理やり含めることは避けてください。 - [参考ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: あらら。すみません。以後気をつけます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。

```
localMovieFilePath = "/var/foo/hoge/"
localMovieFileName = "sample.mp4"

moviePath = localMovieFilePath! + localMovieFileName!
print("moviePath = " + moviePath)
```

で、moviePathの値を見てみると、

```
moviePath = file:///var/foo/hoge/sample.mp4
```

となっていたので、`file://` を削除して

```
moviePath = /var/foo/hoge/sample.mp4
```

としてみたところ、動画ファイルが正常に再生されました。

どういう条件で `file:///` が付与されるのかは
分かりませんが、取り敢えず問題は回避出来ました。